# Total number of vowels in a string

Tags: java, string

I am getting error saying "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"

```
public class StringWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("Ahmedabad");
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println(s.length());
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if(s[i].equals("A")||s[i].equals("a")||s[i].equals("e")||
               s[i].equals("E")||s[i].equals("i")||s[i].equals("I")||
               s[i].equals("o")||s[i].equals("O")||s[i].equals("u")||
               s[i].equals("U"))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Vowels in a string: "+count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(s[i].equals("A")||s[i].equals("a")||s[i].equals("e")||s[i].equals("E")||s[i].equals("i")
            ||s[i].equals("I")||s[i].equals("o")||s[i].equals("O")||s[i].equals("u")||s[i].equals("U"))
```

`equals` method `compares` two `strings`. Here you want to compare character.

use `s.charAt(i)` instead of `s[i]` since you want to `compare` two `characters`. To get the `character` at the `index i` `charAt(index)` method can be used. Two compare two character `== operator` is used.

```
if(s.charAt(i)=='A'||s.charAt(i)=='E'||s.charAt(i)=='I'||s.charAt(i)=='O'||s.charAt(i)=='U')||s.charAt(i)=='a'||s.charAt(i)=='e'||s.charAt(i)=='i'||s.charAt(i)=='o'||s.charAt(i)=='u')
```

Comment: **NO**, `s.charAt(i) == 'A'`

Comment: @Rahul We know what you mean, but it may help clarify your answer for others if you explicitly mention why `charAt()` should be used, and that `[]` cannot be used to access characters in a `String`.

Comment: @JasonC Ok.. i will do.

Answer (score 2):

`Strings` cannot be accessed by `someString[index]` (this notation is used for *arrays*).

Use `charAt(index)` instead, but note that `charAt()` returns a `char`, so you have to compare it with `==` not with `equals()` that is used for `String`s.

You can also simplify this by:

```
if ("AaEeIiOoUu".contains(Character.toString(s.charAt(i))) )
{...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `s` is a `String`, but you treated it like an `array` by doing `s[i]`.

You should use 
`s.charAt(i) // a method of String class which returns the char at the index i`
instead of `s[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Java `String` objects aren't character arrays, and you can't use array syntax with them. Instead, you need to use `charAt`, which returns a `char`, not a `String` like you're apparently expecting, and you would need to use `==` to compare primitives:

```
if(s.charAt(i) == 'a' || ...)
```

Additionally, you can use the `indexOf` method to dramatically simplify your `if` statement:

```
static final String VOWELS = "aeiouAEIOU";

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    if(VOWELS.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) > -1
        count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are using `String s` here. There is no `index` there. Use `char` array from `s`. Or you can use `s.charAt(index)`

Answer (score -1):

**INCORRECT. PLEASE DISREGARD**

You need to convert the string to an array.

```
    s.ToCharArray();
```

**Note:** this is c# code, I don't know if it is similar to java.

Comment: Converting the string to an array *would* allow you to use `[]` to access characters, but you don't "need" to do this to perform the task the OP is trying to perform.

Comment: @Jason Ok. Thankyou for clarifying. I am unfamiliar with java, so I wasn't sure if I was right anyway haha.